# Output t.test results to a data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame of values from individuals linked to groups. I want to identify those groups who have mean values greater than the mean value plus one standard deviation for the whole data set. To do this, I'm calculating the mean value and standard deviation for the entire data frame and then running pairwise t-tests to compare to each group mean. I'm running into trouble outputting the results.

```
> head(df)

  individual  group  value
1 11559638    75     0.371
2 11559641    75     0.367
3 11559648    75     0.410
4 11559650    75     0.417
5 11559652    75     0.440
6 11559654    75     0.395

> allvalues <- data.frame(mean=rep(mean(df$value), length(df$individual)), sd=rep(sd(df$value),  length(df$individual)))

> valueplus <- with(df, by(df, df$individual, function(x) t.test(allvalues$mean + allvalues$sd, df$value, data=x)))

> tmpplus

-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
df$individuals: 10
NULL
-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
df$individuals: 20
NULL
-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
df$individuals: 21

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  allvalues$mean + allvalues$sd and df$value 
t = 84.5217, df = 4999, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0 
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.04676957 0.04899068 
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
0.4719964 0.4241162
```

How do I get the results into a data frame? I'd expect the output to look something like this:

```
      groups  t        df     p-value  mean.x    mean.y
    1 10      NULL     NULL   NULL     NULL      NULL
    2 20      NULL     NULL   NULL     NULL      NULL 
    3 21      84.5217  4999   2.2e-16  0.4719964 0.4241162
```

Comment: This looks very suspect from a statistical point of view. Wouldn't it be wiser to run an ANOVA and then report the results of p-values that have been adjusted for multiple comparisons?

Comment: @DWin Beat me to it. You are going to run into serious issues here because you are performing multiple comparisons. If you do not adjust the significance level (by using something like a Bonferroni adjustment), you are increasing the chances of ending up with Type I error.

Comment: You might try going over to CrossValidated to get your methodological issues sorted before asking us about programming...?

Comment: [@coffeinjunky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2378649/coffeinjunky) your answer for applying t-test to multiple groups is wrong. Since you've used `mtcars$mpg`, the test is applied to the whole data set and not to values of specific id(group). I can't comment due to low reputation but just wanted to point that out. If possible, please provide an alternative.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From a purely programming perspective, you are asking how to get the output of `t.test` into a `data.frame`. Try the following, using `mtcars`:

```
library(broom)
tidy(t.test(mtcars$mpg))
  estimate statistic      p.value parameter conf.low conf.high
1 20.09062  18.85693 1.526151e-18        31 17.91768  22.26357
```

Or for multiple groups:

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% group_by(vs) %>% do(tidy(t.test(.$mpg)))
# A tibble: 2 x 9
# Groups:   vs [2]
     vs estimate statistic  p.value parameter conf.low conf.high method            alternative
  <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>             <chr>      
1     0     16.6      18.3 1.32e-12        17     14.7      18.5 One Sample t-test two.sided  
2     1     24.6      17.1 2.75e-10        13     21.5      27.7 One Sample t-test two.sided
```

Needless to say, you'll need to adjust the code to fit your specific setting.